# Only show Multiple of 2 in a form 'number' field

Tags: html, forms

I've got a HTML form that has a php action, I want the form to be populated with a 'number' type field that will only display values that are a multiple of 2. IE only shows 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10. Not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

```
<form action="confrim.php" method="post">
Number of Tickets <input type="number" name="ticketnum" size="2"><br /><br />
<input type ="submit" name="confirm" >
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you're copy+pasting from your code, you might note that your form action might be misspelled (`confrim` > `confirm`). Not sure if that was intentional, but a heads up anyway.

Comment: Why are you using a text field instead of a dropdown if you want to limit the choices? You can programmatically generate a select if you don't want to hard-code all the options as shown in oblig's answer below. Just use a while loop that starts at zero and increments by two to output each option.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting some javascript validation on the blur event of the input object?
For example, how about something like this:

onblur="javascript:if (this.value % 2 !=0) {this.value=''; this.focus();} return false;"

```
<input type="number" name="ticketnum" size="2" onblur="javascript:if (this.value % 2 !=0) {this.value=''; this.focus();} return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<select>` element.

```
<select name="ticketnum">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5, you can use the **step** attribute along with **min** and **required** to achieve this using browser validation.

`<input type="number" min="0" step="2" required>`